# What is 'llvm-gcc-4.2' doing in '/usr' on my Yosemite system?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, llvm-gcc

In `/usr` on my (migrated) Yosemite system I have some old (2011-12) directories that look out of place to me:

```
/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2
/usr/include/gcc/darwin/4.2
```

What are these? Are they current; can I get rid of them? I have the latest Xcode and command line tools installed, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the Xcode command line tools, but `llvm-gcc` is no longer used, so it looks like they haven't been cleaned-up from a previous version.

I think it's best to leave them alone as I cannot see how they will cause an issue; however if they do seem to be causing issues, then `mv` them to xxx-DELETE_ME and see where you are in a few weeks time. If everything is OK then delete them then.

Comment: Should they have any particular owner (currently `$(whoami):staff`)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Not sure to be honest, but that sounds ok to me.  What is the owner of `clang`? (`ls -l $(which clang)`).

Comment: That's owned by `root:wheel`.

Comment: So are these installed by the *current* Xcode, or by the *current* CLI installation, or were they put there a while ago (and just migrated)?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Hmm; something is wrong then I would say.  If they really bother you then `mv` them to `xxx-DELETE_ME` and see where you are in a few weeks time.  If everything is OK then delete them then.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius They must have been installed as part of a previous Xcode command line tools installation and have fallen into disuse. It's also possible that having `root` as the owner is a newer concept as well.

Comment: The permission change (if it is one) is my fault: I deleted them and then put them right back after having second thoughts.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius OK; that makes more sense then.

Comment: I'll try renaming for a wile to see what happens; `pip` will be the test, I think, judging from what's popping up as "related".

Answer (score 0):

It is just a simlink to clang.

Go to /usr/bin and type `ls -l | grep llvm` you should see *llvm-gcc -> clangcc* if it is a simlink